# Avoiding memory leak caused by objectSpill inside CompiledScript instance in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

We maintain a cache of CompiledScripts to reduce script execution time in Nashorn. (Java 8x112)

Each CompiledScript instance has an instance of the engine used for compiling the code. An object called objectSpill is holding onto all the scope level objects of that engine causing memory leak.

Before each execution, we make sure the we use a separate bindings for evaluating the CompiledScript. This bindings is ScriptContext.GLOBAL

Is there any way to avoid this?.

Leak stack from VisualVM shown below
[image]

Comment: Note that Nashorn in now deprecated and will be removed: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335

Comment: I am aware. Unfortunately, code rewriting is not an option now.